# Creating custom corpus in NLTK using CSV file

Tags: python, nltk, corpus

Hey guys I'm presently creating custom corpus for text classification in NLTK Python using the following

```
corpus_create = CategorizedTaggedCorpusReader('/home/classification', '(training|test).*',cat_file='cat.txt')

len(corpus_Create.categories())
```

Then we utilize a high information words function and a training_test_feat function to return train_feats and test_feats.

Currently we create two folders called Training and Test in which the classified data is put with a cat file describing the folder/filename  with POS,NEG,NEU

```
Training/File10 POS
Test/File2 NEG 
Training/File445 NEU 
...........
```

Now if we have a CSV file with Column 1 having text and COlumn2 having classificiation for instance

```
   Text      Classification 
   Good           POS 
   This is nice   POS 
   Thats  bad     NEG 
   This is a cat  NEU
```

How can we write a function to directly create a corpus from a CSV file?

Thanks a lot

Comment: If you have them in a single tab-delimited file, you should use `panda` to read it in as dataframes and you can train a classifier with `nltk` or `sklearn` easily.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are unpacking or reading data from a CSV file you can use Pythons' CSV module. The following code opens the file and appends everything to a list which you can then feed into the classifier.

```
import csv

training_set = []

with open('path/to/text.csv') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
    for row in reader:
        training_set.append((row['Text'], row['Classification']))


print training_set
```

If your classifier has the ability to be updated then you can skip creating the list training_set and just do .update(row['Text'], row['Classification'])